# Check multiple POP3 accounts from one inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have multiple domain specific email address that I'd like to check from a single Gmail login. I've previously seen a set up where multiple inboxes or accounts were accessible from the left side bar simply by clicking on the name/email address.

I've already added these accounts to Gmail, enabled to send mail as, and enabled the multiple accounts feature in Labs. I'm unsure of what to do next to move each of the accounts inboxes to the left sidebar. I looked at maybe creating Labels, but this doesn't look as I've seen it before.

How can I list my accounts in the left sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you have already set up filtering so that email from other accounts are labeled? If not, you should set up a filtering rule for each account, so that incoming emails are tagged with an account-specific label.

Click the gear icon -> *Settings* -> *Filters* -> *Create new filter*, and enter the account name in the *to* field.

Now, to display each account in the sidebar.
The look of labels have changed slightly. Most labels are now collapsed under *More*:

[image: Display more labels]

Hovering over a label, click the down arrow to open a menu, which allows you to specify that a label should be always shown in the top section:

[image: Label menu]

Now, the label is displayed in the top section of the label list. If you selected *Show if unread*, the label will only be displayed if there are unread messages there.